# How to fix accordion bug in my responsive website using Foundation

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor, responsive-design

What I am trying to do is create a responsive navigation bar that, when in mobile, it is displayed as a hamburger icon that loads an accordion menu. This has gone well overall, but I have encountered a bug when the user leaves the mobile version and enters the desktop version.

When the user expands the accordion and switches to the desktop-version the related tabs are still open and still act as accordion items.

A couple of things that I have tried is switching classes using the onResize function in order to remove the accordion class from the navigation bar. This only made things worse, not only didn't it work, but when the user entered the desktop version, the nav bar still acted as though it was in the mobile version, adding in white space where the rest of the navigation bar should have been.

I have also tried reloading the page using the onResize function as well. This worked a little better as it refreshes and closes all the tabs, however, upon reloading, yoiu can still catch a glimpse of the white space that is added in before the page is fully refreshed.

```
<nav class="navigation navigation-multiple" id="navigation-main" data-toggler=".navigation-show">
   <ul class="accordion navigation-menu margin-bottom-medium" data-accordion data-multi-expand="true" data-allow-all-closed="true">
      <li class="nav-link-with-sub" data-accordion-item>
         @Html.ActionLink("Buy", "Buy", "Home", new { }, new { @class = "nav- 
         link accordian-title" })
         <ul class="navigation-menu-sub accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("How to Buy", "Buy", "Home", new { }, new { 
               @class = "nav-link" })
            </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there anything else I can try to fix this bug in order to provide a more user-friendly experience?

Comment: Is this that serious of an issue? I mean, not many users will do that switch if the site is well designed for both screens. Are you testing with a browser on a desktop/laptop?

Comment: To me and the person i am working with, yes it is a problem. Weve already discussed how users will interact with it, but we are also presenting this website and the transition is a part of it. We just want to make this clean and efficient.